# Samsung Galaxy S4 [GT- I9500] - Android 4.2.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 4.2-jelly-bean, 5.0-lollipop, 4.3-jelly-bean

Currently working with Android 4.2.2.
I'm a bit curious if it is worth the upgrade to Android 5.
How can I know the improvements related to 4.2.2, - I'm currently not having any problems with it.

I don't want to mess things up; is the upgrade worth it? Could it include new bugs?
What are the downsides of higher versions than 4.2.2?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend you upgrade to Android L / 5.0.2.

There a numerous changes relating to performance, new features, and battery life. Android L gives a completely different (better, in my opinion) feel to the phone and fixes many of the bugs from previous versions.

To answer your question about including new bugs; it's inevitable. But if they are addressed, it's highly likely they will be fixed in the future.

Comment: Is there any place the summerize new features in each version+ major bugs added?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.android.com/versions/lollipop-5-0/) and [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html) for more information of the new features of Android 5.0